# Is there method .predict in official python bindings for fastText

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, fasttext

I know there are unofficial bindings with .predict method in python(fasttext, pyfasttext) but they do not work with recent models trained on on official FastText bash tool or do not have all the options. Official python bindings have only load_model(path)and tokenize(text) methods described , which sounds strange as with this you can not do any predictions. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Python package built and installed according to this link https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/README.md#building-fasttext-for-python. I consider it official.
The model object loaded via load_model has the requested predict method.

Comment: Right, it all is in the code, but not in docs which are somewhat vague